# RewriteRule /change-email.htm?e=someone@somewhere.com&h=xxxxxx

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite URL's of this form:

`/change-email.htm?e=someone@somewhere.com&h=xxxxxx`

to:

`/change-email/?e=someone@somewhere.com&h=xxxxx`

I've done this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/change-email\.htm$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^e=(.*)&h=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /change-email/?e=%1&h=%2 [R=301,L]
```

but this is rewriting:

`/change-email.htm?e=someone@somewhere.com&h=xxxxxx`

to:

`/change-email/?e=someonesomewhere.com&h=xxxxx`

Note that it is removing the `@` symbol.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?

**UPDATE**

Using

`http://www.example.com/change-email.htm?e=someone@somewhere.com` redirects perfectly

however:

`http://example.com/change-email.htm?e=someone@somewhere.com` redirects to

`http://example.com/change-email/?e=someonesomewhere.com` (@ symbol removed)

Here's my complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch 301 /images/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1

RewriteRule ^gv5.htm(.*) /get-v5-key/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^change-email\.htm(.*)$ /change-email/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe\.htm(.*)$ /unsubscribe/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^renew-support\.htm(.*)$ /renew-support/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^retrieve-license-code\.htm(.*)$ /retrieve-registration-key/$1 [R=301,NE,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE**

Answered my own question.

Comment: After your update... yes, that is a puzzle. There would not seem to be anything in your .htaccess file that would influence this? Have you checked the network traffic directly, to make sure there isn't an additional response by WordPress?! However, a couple of points about your .htaccess file: You should not mix mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite as the order of execution is unpredictable from server to server. The mod_alias directive should be converted to mod_rewrite. Also, what are you hoping to match with `(.*)` at the end of your `RewriteRule` pattern?

Comment: What happens when you request the URL directly? eg. `http://example.com/change-email/?e=someone@somewhere.com`

Comment: Hah, that strips out the @ too.  Doesn't matter what page or parm name either, it strips out the @.  Looks like something in WordPress for sure.

Comment: @w3d not quite sure what you mean by the mod_alias part.  The (.*) is intended to match anything  I guess.  I use multiple parms on most pages with long and short form names (to stop links wrapping in emails for example).  Can I dispense with it?

Comment: Yes, it does look like a WordPress issue. Is the `@` actually being removed from the browsers address bar? (In which case WordPress itself would seem to be triggering an external redirect - which should show in the network traffic.)

Comment: "mod_alias" - this is just an aside in this particular case as there does not appear to be a conflict. However, `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive, not mod_rewrite. Apache does not process the .htaccess file from top to bottom, it processes the different "modules" separately in an order decided by the server config. So, you could find that the `RewriteRule` directives are in fact processed _before_ the `RedirectMatch` directive - this is unpredictable and server dependent. So it is always recommended to avoid mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives.

Comment: Just to make sure... you don't have any other .htaccess files in subdirectories?

Comment: "multiple parms on most pages" - if you are referring to "URL parameters" (ie. the query string) then yes, it can be dispensed with. The `RewriteRule` pattern does not match against the query string, so the `(.*)` would indeed be redundant. Providing you don't include a query string in the substitution then the original query string on the request is passed through unaltered by default.

Comment: OK thanks, yes I am referring to URL parameters. I'll get rid of the pattern matching and see how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a WordPress one.  It was stripping out the @ when re-writing the non www address to the www address.  Problem resolved by adding my old redirect code (which I thought I could dispense with) to top of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm guessing that WordPress is perhaps (blindly) sanitizing the request URI to prevent XSS attacks?! Anyway, it's better (quicker and less work for your server) to do this type of redirection in .htaccess (or better still in your server config if you have your own server).

Comment: @w3d The WordPress parameter-handling code is a disaster. I'm not surprised that it corrupted the data, and I would bet that it was unintentional on the part of the WordPress developers.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to resolve this by using the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive? However, this is admittedly a little puzzling, as even *special characters* shouldn't be removed entirely, just converted to their hexcode equivalent. The `NE` flag allows special characters to be passed through untouched.

However, your current rules can be greatly simplified and improved.

Currently, every single request is being processed by the `RewriteRule` pattern `^(.*)$`, so this is inefficient. You only need to process requests for `/change-email.htm`, so this can be rewritten as a one liner (no `RewriteCond` directives are required):

```
RewriteRule ^change-email\.htm$ /change-email/ [R=301,NE,L]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` is processed *first*. Only when the `RewriteRule` pattern matches are the preceeding `RewriteCond` directives processed.

You don't need to match against the query string since you aren't doing anything with it, except passing it straight through to the substitution - which is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great simplification which I've put in place.  However, it didn't solve my problem.  I've got another re-write rule that is passing the @ character just fine.  This one isn't however.  I think the problem must lay in Wordpress somewhere.  Poking about to see if I can find it!

Comment: Yes, I think there must be other factors at play here. By itself the above `RewriteRule` should work OK, in fact the `NE` flag is not strictly necessary here. Presumably you are also _internally rewriting_ the request back to the `.htm` version of the URL? Is that functioning correctly? (Or is that not necessary?)

Comment: OK, I've worked out the cause.  I just have no idea of the solution.  See notes in question.